# String Interoperability: Fortran to C++

Tags: c++, fortran

I would like to send a Fortran string to my C++ application, I tried to do this, **but I got this linker error:**

`unresolved external symbol for_cpystr referenced in function my_long_calc`

**My Fortran Static Lib Code (Visual Fortran):**

```
module my_interfaces
    use iso_c_binding
        interface
            subroutine fortran_message(msg) bind(C, name = 'fortran_message')
                use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

                character(kind = c_char), dimension(*), intent(out) :: msg

            end subroutine fortran_message
        end interface
end module my_interfaces

! My long calc subroutine
subroutine my_long_calc() BIND(C, name = 'my_long_calc')
    use, intrinsic :: ISO_C_BINDING
    use my_interfaces
    implicit none

    ! A single variable:
    character(len = 40, kind = c_char) :: msg

    msg = "this is a msg from fortran"

    ! Send a message to the C++ application:
    call fortran_message(msg)
end subroutine my_long_calc
```

**My C++ Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  void my_long_calc(void);
  void fortran_message(char* msg);
}

void fortran_message(char* msg)
{
  std::cout << *msg << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    my_long_calc();

    return 0;
}
```

Please, what I have to do **to link this library and get the "msg" string inside the C++ application?**

Comment: What Fortran compiler are you using? Also, please post your full Fortran compiler command-line or options.

Comment: Do you include the Fortran runtime library when linking using the C++ linker?  As in the previous comment, please show how you are compiling and linking

Comment: As mentioned, are you including the object file generated from Fortran compilation to C++ linker settings? Also both compilers should generate either 32 or 64 bit compilations for compatibility.

Comment: Also asked in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/815905